# Subtracting Two Columns with a Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `dataframe` and would like to subtract two columns of the previous row, provided that the previous row has the same `Name` value. If it does not, then I would like it yield `NAN` and fill with `-`. My `groupby` expression yields the error, `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`, which is very ambiguous. What am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Person A', 5, 8], ['Person A', 13, 11], ['Person B', 11, 32], ['Person B', 15, 20]], columns=['Names', 'Value', 'Value1'])
df['diff'] = df.groupby('Names').apply(df['Value'].shift(1) - df['Value1'].shift(1)).fillna('-')
print df
```

Desired Output:

```
      Names  Value  Value1  diff
0  Person A      5       8     -
1  Person A     13      11    -3
2  Person B     11      32     -
3  Person B     15      20   -21
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `lambda x` and change `df['Value']` to `x['Value']`, similar with `Value1` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('Names')
               .apply(lambda x: x['Value'].shift(1) - x['Value1'].shift(1))
               .fillna('-')
               .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Names  Value  Value1 diff
0  Person A      5       8    -
1  Person A     13      11   -3
2  Person B     11      32    -
3  Person B     15      20  -21
```

Another solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Names')['Value','Value1'].shift()
print (df1)
   Value  Value1
0    NaN     NaN
1    5.0     8.0
2    NaN     NaN
3   11.0    32.0
df['diff'] = (df1.Value - df1.Value1).fillna('-')

print (df)
      Names  Value  Value1 diff
0  Person A      5       8    -
1  Person A     13      11   -3
2  Person B     11      32    -
3  Person B     15      20  -21
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it this way:

```
In [76]: df['diff'] = (-df.groupby('Names')[['Value1','Value']].shift(1).diff(axis=1)['Value1']).fillna(0)

In [77]: df
Out[77]:
      Names  Value  Value1  diff
0  Person A      5       8   0.0
1  Person A     13      11  -3.0
2  Person B     11      32   0.0
3  Person B     15      20 -21.0
```